# Cramers V in SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, statistics

So apart from the official documentation on stats_crosstab, I can't find anything on how to run Cramer's V. Here's the documentation for stats_crosstab: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions151.htm .

I've tried a few version of this:

```
SELECT 
STATS_CROSSTAB(JOB, AGE, 'CRAMERS_V_OBS') CRAMERS_V,
STATS_CROSSTAB(JOB, AGE, 'CRAMERS_V_SIG') CRAMERS_V_VALUE,
STATS_CROSSTAB(JOB, AGE, 'PHI_COEFFICIENT') PHI_COEFFICIENT
FROM bank_telemarketing_data;
```

Anyone know what I'm misspelling/why I'm getting an error?
The error I'm getting is 'illegal arguement'.

Thanks

Comment: As per the documentation you quoted, there is no input of `CRAMERS_V_OBS` or `CRAMERS_V_SIG`, only `CRAMERS_V`.